# Cannot draw on second Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, canvas

I wonder if someone can point me to right direction, I have an HTML 5 Canvas that I'm iterating over twice.
The problem is I can draw on the first Canvas perfectly fine but Not the second one, I can not draw on the second canvas. Why and what's the solution ?

```
<% 
            for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        %>

        <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sketchpad.css">
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="js/sketchpad.js"></script>
            </head>
           <body onload="init();">
                <div id="main-content">
                    <canvas id="can" width="600" height="400" ></canvas>
                </div>   
            </body>
        </html>

        <%
        }
        %>
```

Comment: id values on elements must be unique. Also you've got your loop around the *entire page*, which doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried all sorts of ways including what you've just suggested without any joy.

Comment: Well post those tries then.

Comment: ` <body onload="init();">
        <div id="main-content">
            <% for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){ %>
                <canvas id="can" class="<%= i %>" width="600" height="400" ></canvas>
            <% } %>
        </div>   
    </body>` I thought this would work but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pointy mentioned, you are looping the entire page, so that will be best changed, and also, you're creating two different canvas' but with the same ID for that and it's container. I don't know JSP so you'll probably have to correct the variable **i** to be output properly. But you get the idea

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sketchpad.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/sketchpad.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body onload="init();">

        <%
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        %>

        <div class="canvas-container-<%= i %>">
            <canvas class="canvas-<%= i %>" width="600" height="400" ></canvas>
        </div>

        <%
        }
        %>

    </body>

</html>
```

Just remember in your JS or wherever your manipulating the Canvas, to use the '.canvas-XXX' (XXX is the unique id from the **i** variable) instead of '#can'.